# How can I use the Python debugger (with breakpoints) while using the interactive mode in VS Code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Here is a simplified example to show the problem I have in VS Code:

```py
#%% cell 1
import time

def myfunc():
    a = 5  # <-- Put breakpoint here
    b = 0
    return a/b

#%% cell 2
t = time.time()
print("started at", t)
myfunc()
```

I put a breakpoint at `a = 5` then I press `SHIFT+ENTER` twice to execute both cells.
The interactive window shows the print, but then show the exception: `ZeroDivisionError: division by zero` instead of activating my breakpoint.

**How can I activate the debugger without losing the current variables** (like `t`) from the interactive session?

I want to make it stop at the breakpoint the next time I press `SHIFT+ENTER` and be able to step through `myfunc`.

**EDIT:**

As @MingJie-MSFT pointed out, I can use `CTRL+SHIFT+P` > `Jupyter: Debug Current Cell` command to enable the debugger.

Is it normal that when I invoke this command, I immediately see line 3445 of interactiveshell.py, instead of breaking into my code?
[image: Internal debugger code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I press SHIFT+ENTER twice to execute both cells.

**SHIFT+ENTER** means run current cell instead of debug the cell.

[image]

You can click **Debug Cell** to achieve it.

[image]

Read [document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support-py#_jupyter-code-cells) for more details.

You can also use jupyter notebook. It's the same as interactive window.

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  I removed those commands as to not clutter the editor. But I found we can `CTRL+SHIFT+P` > `Debug Current Cell` when needed.